# Is there a word/phrase to describe a person "who hates someone rather than hate their views"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Let's say there is a person called X. X is a good person, in general. He has a problematic view about something, let's say, homophobia. So, here is the conversation between Y and Z.

Y: X is homophobic. I hate him.

Z: I don't support X's views, but I do not hate the person. I hate his views.

Is there a word/phrase/expression to describe Y?

Comment: “Hate the sin, love the sinner” may be a useful idiom here, though it describes Z